# Problems with OpenCL/OpenGL Texture interop / windows

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

To improve rendering quality I'm writing on a versatile separable downscaler in OpenCL 1.1.

The basic image (covering only a small part of the final image) is rendered into a very large framebuffer.  Then its color-attached texture is downsampled and placed into another texture via OpenCL.  Finally a screen-aligned quad gets rendered to show the result.

So far the idea.  What do we have:

- 2 instances of the downscaler-kernel (it stores the results with coordinates exchanged (i.e. as (y,x) )
- inputTexture (the color attachment of the rtt-framebuffer)
- tempTexture, size: inputHeight x outputWidth, created with CL_MEM_READ_WRITE
- outputTexture

Running `kernel_instance_1( <otherParams>, inputTexture, tempTexture )` produces the desired result, **but only in the very first frame** - somehow the changes happening in the animation don't show up at all.  As I get no errors (see below) I assume the kernel runs every frame, but the source texture content stays the same (which it doesn't, I also have a live-output of that texture).

*`Question:`* Do I have to call clCreateFromGLTexture2D() every time the contents of the framebuffer changed?

**EDIT** I just realized: the inputTexture is still attached to the framebuffer object's `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` - may this be a problem? **ENDEDIT**

Running `kernel_instance_2( <otherParams>, tempTexture, outputTexture )` yields no visible result, even with a barrier enqueued between both kernel calls.  I.e. the outputTexture stays empty.

*`Question:`* Do I need to release and re-acquire the texture object `tempTexture` in between both kernel calls, so OpenCL sees the changes?

Just to see what OpenCL-calls are made, the following output was produced:

```
clCreateKernel( separable_X )
clRetainMemObject( separable_X::convolution )
clCreateKernel( separable_Y )
clRetainMemObject( separable_Y::convolution )
clCreateFromGLTexture2D( separable_X::dst + separable_y::src, texID=24, usage=temporary (source and target) )
clCreateFromGLTexture2D( separable_Y::dst, texID=18, usage=target )
clCreateFromGLTexture2D( separable_X::src, texID=22, usage=source )
clRetainMemObject( separable_X::dst )
clRetainMemObject( separable_Y::src )
clRetainMemObject( separable_Y::dst )
clRetainMemObject( clearEmpty::dst )
clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects( count=3 )
clEnqueueBarrier()
clSetKernelArg( separable_X::convert )
clSetKernelArg( separable_X::offset )
clSetKernelArg( separable_X::convolution )
clSetKernelArg( separable_X::dst )
clSetKernelArg( separable_X::src )
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( separable_X, (1440, 1080, 0), waiting4 0 events )
clSetKernelArg( separable_Y::convert )
clSetKernelArg( separable_Y::offset )
clEnqueueBarrier()
clSetKernelArg( separable_Y::convolution )
clSetKernelArg( separable_Y::dst )
clSetKernelArg( separable_Y::src )
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( separable_Y, (540, 1440, 0), waiting4 0 events )
clEnqueueBarrier()
clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects( count=3 )
```

If any call had produced an error, it would've been inside that output.

Another situation I get lots of times is that `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects()` returns error code -9999, which somebody filed as "NVidia: Illegal read or write to a buffer".

*`Question:`* could it be that `write_imagef()` does not clamp the color value if any component exceeds 1.0f and the storage format is RGBA8?  So that'd actually mean one must write `write_imagef( texture, (int2)coord, clamp( color, 0.f, 1.f ) );`...

Thanks a lot in advance - this gets me banging my head since nearly a week...

**EDIT**
Some more infos that might be worth mentioning:

***how I can distinguish the two instances?***
There are 2 distinct `__kernel` functions with different names (`separable_X` and `separable_Y`) inside the program source, which both have the same body calling the `separable()`-function.

***how do I sync between GL and CL?***
 - the function taking care of acquiring GL objects issues a `glFinish()` before calling `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects()`
 - I wait for completion of `clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects()` by using cl_events (likely to change in the future)

Comment: How are you synchronizing between OpenGL and OpenCL?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Please see my edits.

Comment: Q: Do I have to call clCreateFromGLTexture2D() every time the contents of the framebuffer changed?
A: No, you only do that once to create an OpenCL image from an OpenGL texture. That should happen before the loop where it is used. 

Q: Do I need to release and re-acquire the texture object tempTexture in between both kernel calls, so OpenCL sees the changes?
A: No. Once acquired for OpenCL you can use it there as much as you need.

Comment: Q: could it be that write_imagef() does not clamp the color value if any component exceeds 1.0f and the storage format is RGBA8? 
A: No, it works perfectly. We use it all the time.

Comment: You're using glFinish before clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects; you should also call clFinish AFTER clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects. Read section 9.8.6.2 of the OpenCL 1.1 specification carefully.

Comment: @dithermaster: why don't you make an answer of it?  Thank you very much - so it seems my OpenCL Management classes are bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using glFinish before clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects which is correct, but you should *also* call clFinish AFTER clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects. Read section 9.8.6.2 of the OpenCL 1.1 specification carefully.

Also, to your other questions:

> Do I have to call clCreateFromGLTexture2D() every time the contents of the framebuffer changed?

No, you only do that once to create an OpenCL image from an OpenGL texture. That should happen before the loop where it is used.

> Do I need to release and re-acquire the texture object tempTexture in between both kernel calls, so OpenCL sees the changes?

No. Once acquired for OpenCL you can use it there as much as you need.

> could it be that write_imagef() does not clamp the color value if any component exceeds 1.0f and the storage format is RGBA8?

No, it works perfectly. We use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks again, mostly for the clarification on my "other" questions.  In fact those led me to finding out, my boilerplate CL-wrapper had some problems. After replacing that boilerplate with simple CL code, everything works as expected.

Comment: Further findings: if enqueuing two kernels directly after each other that use the same texture, you need to enqueue a barrier in between - or at least some command like clSetKernelArg, that provides for ending one kernel before starting the next! (with out of order exec disabled!)

Comment: That's very interesting, and sounds like a bug in the runtime.

Comment: Well, when it comes to OpenCL I'm still a noob, so maybe I just misinterpreted some errors I got.  I wouldn't go as far as suspecting a runtime bug just yet.